# Streaming large ipa files to iOS devices

Tags: c#, ipa, isapi

Hey everyone I am working on a custom app store for iOS. However, I am having a problem when my system tries to stream large ipa files to the device. Sense there is no way to tell the device the total size of the file during the stream the status bar on the iOS device wont budge until the file is finished downloading then it almost completely fills the status bar in an instant and installs the file. This may leave users to think that the download isn't working at all. I am trying to find an alternative way to handle these large ipa files. I am currently thinking that I could allow the device to make a direct request to the file without hitting any .Net runtime code. I would probably be able to handle this through an ISAPI filter, but then I would need a way to authenticate that request to make sure the user has access to that download. Any advice or input would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider pushing the apps into S3 and sending out signed CloudFront URLs to authenticated users:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

Alternatively, you could just give the .ipa files very obscure names that would be hard to guess.

Comment: Or just send the Content-Length header in your response.